# Adding custom made north arrow to ArcGIS Pro Project

Tags: arcgis-pro, style, north-arrow

I need to be able to add a custom north arrow to achieve a standardized look for maps I make for my company.  I've been reading through the ArcGIS Pro documentation and have come to a loss on what I'm missing.  The documentation clearly states as follows.

[image]

I am attempting to add the north arrow to the "Favorites" style.  However, nowhere do I see the option for "New Item".  All I can find is the add, create, or import options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation here appears to be wrong - I get the same result as you. (perhaps the documentation has been completed for a yet to be released version of ArcGIS Pro)

If you click New Style here, it will allow you to create a custom style (as opposed to the included system styles).

Once the new style is created, I found I had to open one of the existing styles such as ArcGIS 2D (right-click > Manage) select a style item and Right-Click > Copy.  Then in my new custom style I Right-Click Paste.  Once this was done I could right-click within my new style and create New style items.

That all said, I couldn't find any North Arrows in either the existing styles nor an option to create one.

---

I just found the "New Item" (although there's no North Arrow option in it that I can see).  On the Home tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you add a North Arrow, you can change the .emf file associated with it by right-clicking -> properties -> point symbol -> properties -> layers -> file...

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that to do that, you have to first insert a default north arrow, then make your modifications. When you're happy with the result you right-click in the content pane on the object (North Arrow by default) and in the context menu you can click on save to style. The object is then saved as a north arrow in a custom style.

[image: Save a custom north arrow to a style]